# How can I work with a 999 in a BizTalk orchestration?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

I need to be able to accept (not generate) a 999 file in BizTalk and run it through a map and some business logic. If I actually add the 999 schema to my project, then when deployed I get the error:

> Cannot locate document specification because multiple schemas matched the message type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006#X12_00501_999"

...which would seem to indicate that the 999 schema is already in the Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.BaseArtifacts DLL. But looking in the DLL after I reference it in the project, I only see the 997 (X12_997_Root).

So, suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Argh, 60 seconds after I posted this I realized the problem - an ancient application that was never cleaned off the server that also had the 999 schema in it. Nevermind...